# How can i open DevTools from my pc in my android?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm wondering how can I open DevTools from my Windows PC in my android phone? is this possible?

EDIT: My question was not clear enough, an example of what I want is: I open a DevTools on a page (Using my PC) It will load the data from this page, so I want to access the exact same DevTools (With the loaded data) using my android phone which is on the same network

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open an RDP session to Windows to launch and view Windows
applications.

See Microsoft app
[Remote Desktop 8](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android&hl=en&gl=US).

Comment: That's not what I meant, I want to access the actual DevTools on my Windows Computer using my Android phone, not the full computer

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated my post I think I think it should be understandable now.

Comment: If you want to interact with DevTools, you need RDP. Otherwise, you might want a viewer for the PC screen (you will have resolution problems).

Answer (score 0):

Try [eruda](https://github.com/liriliri/eruda)

> It is provided as embeddable javascript and also a bookmarklet
> (pasting bookmarklet in chrome removes the javascript: prefix, so you
> have to type it yourself)

[an easy guide - how to use it on dev.to](https://dev.to/asaoluelijah/how-to-access-dev-tool-on-mobile-browsers-14nd)

---

Try [com.kiwibrowser.browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser)

> Kiwi Browser is mobile Chromium and allows installing extensions.
> Install Kiwi and then install "Mini JS console" Chrome extension(just
> search in Google and install from Chrome extensions website, uBlock
> also works ;). It will become available in Kiwi menu at the bottom and
> will show the console output for the current page.

Comment: Hey! I think I didn't worded well my question, I updated my post, so if you still want to help me, thanks!